# Unable to remove Wi-Fi profile which is created by the same app programmatically

Tags: android, wifi, wifimanager

I have an android application developed by using Xamarin forms, I will show the available wifi networks inside my application using Wifi Manager. User chooses any network and give password then I will add that network and enable the same to connect it. Here is the code

```
var configuredNetworksList = wifiManager.ConfiguredNetworks.ToArray();
 if (configuredNetworksList != null)
    {
      var existingWifiConfig = configuredNetworksList.Where(r => r.Ssid == wifiConfig.Ssid).ToArray();
      foreach (WifiConfiguration temp in existingWifiConfig)
            {
                bool isSuccess = wifiManager.RemoveNetwork(temp.NetworkId);
                wifiManager.SaveConfiguration();
            }
        }

        int id = wifiManager.AddNetwork(wifiConfig);

        wifiManager.SaveConfiguration();

        wifiManager.EnableNetwork(id, true)
```

The above code is working fine. But the problem scenario is,

- I am installing the app and choose the network to connect. For example "wifiX". Its connected.
- Now go to Settings->Wifi in the android device. Here there is only one wifi with SSID "wifiX"(which is added by me) showing.
- Then I am uninstalling the app and re-installing the same app and doing same step to connect with "wifiX". It is connecting to the selected wifi. But now my android device Settings is showing two instances with same SSID "wifiX" in the wifi list.

[image]

Note: As you see in the code, before adding selected network, I am removing all the networks with the same selected ssid.

As per android documentation [Android 6.0 Changes documentation](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes) , we cannot remove the wifi profile which is created by another app.

But in my case, the wifi was created by the same app.

Can anyone help on this?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

notice:

```
var existingWifiConfig = configuredNetworksList.Where(r => r.Ssid == wifiConfig.Ssid).ToArray(); 
//should be SSID, not Ssid.
```

doc is [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiConfiguration.html#SSID).

Comment: Hi @navylover. Thanks for your reply.  As I mentioned app is implemented in Xamarin forms. So it uses C# language. It has property name as Ssid not SSID.

Comment: @ChandranS sorry, my negligence.

Comment: @ChandranS debug and see if 'isSuccess' return true

Comment: Yes. Its giving true for the instance which is created after reinstalling the app. But giving false for the network which is added before uninstalling (I mean network created by the previously installed app).